# Use MDX in order to have the same functionality of "GROUP BY" to show only show an item once, at it's max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

I have a cube that has a Measure of Price and Quantity.  I have two dimensions, Product and Supplier.
Product>Name>Name is the product's name string, and Supplier>Name>Name is the supplier's name string.

I am trying to query the cube to return the max pricing of a product, but my with statement does not seem to be working.

I am trying to create a new reference called "Max Price" as a measure that is just the MAX function around the measure price measure.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Max Value] AS MAX([Measures].[Price])
```

However, when I write the rest and run it, my code it just shows the sum of all the prices for a product name:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[Max Value]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY { 
    ([Tb Product].[Name].[Name] ) }  ON ROWS 
FROM [DS715]
```

**What I want** is just one row with the single max price of each product.

**What it is showing** is a single row with the sum of all product prices.

Data example:

> Product Names: Auto, Plane, Wheels
>
> Product Prices: Auto ($100, $200, $300), Plane ($1000, $2000, $3000),
>   Wheels ($10, $20, $30)

Output:

> What is showing is: Auto: $600 Plane: $6000 Wheel: $60
>
> I would expect: Auto: $300 Plane: $3000 Wheels: $30

Answer (score 0):

In your project define a new measure and select usage as maximum.This will return the maximum sale amount in context of your query.

Adding Screens on comment below

[image: Adding a Measure]

Now setting the usage

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is probably a stupid question, but how do you define a new measure and “select usage as maximum?”

Comment: So open your SSAS Project, In the solution explorer open your cube, Now on the top left hand you will see measures, right click and select new measure. You will see sum selected in usage, select maximum for Price column. Adding a pic shortly

Comment: Check the screens

Comment: I don’t have access to change add a measure that way. I did try to create a measure calculation, but I did the same thing which gives me multiple rows: “MAX([Measure].[Price]). Do you know what the code that is created from doing that?  If I could see why MAX() isn’t working and what I’m missing I could fix it that way.